# Embed google analytics benchmarking report on 3rd party website

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am currently busy with embeddig a Google Analytics dashboard on a third-party website. I've already made a server-side authorization work and I'm able to display some google analytics data.

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to query google analytics benchmark data and show it on third-party website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like Google Analytics benchmark data is available through the API.

Check [this query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) for the possible query parameters through the GA API.

As a workaround, you could either manually pull a csv report from GA, or write an automated script that can do this, depending on what you need.